# Extending a line 20 days into future on chartSeries plot

Tags: r, quantmod

I have added a line to a chart using quantmod. But how can I make it extend out into the future for the next 20 days?

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("SPY", from="2013-01-01", to="2013-09-28")
chartSeries(SPY, TA="addLines(h=c(max(SPY[,c(1:4)])))")
```

Also how can I add its value onto the secondary y axis?

I also tried:

```
 chart_Series(SPY, subset="2013::", type = "candlesticks" ) 
 segments(1, 150, 800, 150)
```

But I could not change the x axis forward.

Comment: Please read the SO rules on how to write a useful post. In particular, please post what you have tried, where you expect to get your data for the "future,"  and what your chart looks like so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the value you want to extend into another object, then merge the object you want to chart with the index of the other object.  This will create rows full of `NA` for the future days.

```
futureLine <- xts(,end(SPY)+1:20)  # create empty object with days we want
futureLine$max <- max(Hi(SPY))     # fill in data
chart_Series(merge(SPY,index(futureLine)), TA="add_TA(futureLine, on=1)")
```

The regular `chartSeries` doesn't like this approach, as it seems to remove all the rows that only contain `NA`.

Comment: Error in `index<-.xts`(`*tmp*`, value = c(1357084800, 1357171200, 1357257600,  : 
  unsupported ‘index’ index type of class ‘POSIXct’ I tried the above but I kee getting a POSTIXct index error. I tried  class(index(SPY)) and I get [1] "Date" so I am not sure what to do do fix this error

Comment: R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform:x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] quantmod_0.4-0 TTR_0.22-0     Defaults_1.1-1 xts_0.9-7      zoo_1.7-10    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.0.2      lattice_0.20-23 tools_3.0.2

Comment: I typed the session info above.

Comment: @adam.888: you reported that same error in a comment on another one of your questions. It's not specific to my answer and is probably caused by a malformed xts object.